# Jquery click/toggle not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I tried some old answers from other questions, but none of them resolved my case. The toggle function is not working fro me. Below is the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".team-member").click(
    function() {
        $(this).children(".description").toggle();
    }
);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="team-member" data-style="meta_below">
    <img alt="yes" src="source/to/img.jpg" title="Candice Rauter">
    <h4 class="light">Name</h4>
    <div class="position">Position Goes Herer</div>
    <p class="description">blablabla</p>
</div>
```

[Link](http://clients.fariadesign.com/geniusjunkie/#our-team) for the section of the website(#our-team section).

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect your site on mobile, using sdk and Chrome, you get

> Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

warnings on your page.

Try using [.on('click')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/629127) rather than `.click()`

```
$(".team-member").on('click', function(){
    $(this).children(".description").toggle();
});
```

This should work even for dynamically added elements. And I think your page is using ajax to load its content (from what I can see in the inspector).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but still not working. Any other recommendations? Thanks

Comment: Since you are using salient, try asking the official support. It's hard to know what they added in their code that could affect this :\